# Indesign Glyphs in table cell disappeared after append text to the same cell

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am working on a js extend script for Adobe Indesign.
I am facing a problem, which is weird, I dont know if its a Adobe Indesign bug or my problem.

The case is: I have to insert some special character to a table, so i have to use find and change Glyphs method to insert those special character in to that table's cell:

```
month12day29.contents = "¢";
app.findChangeGlyphOptions.includeMasterPages = true;
month12day29.characters.everyItem().appliedParagraphStyle ="前ー月大丸";
month12day29.characters[0].properties={appliedFont : 'A-OTF Futo Go B101 Pro',fontStyle: 'Bold'}
app.findGlyphPreferences.appliedFont= 'A-OTF Futo Go B101 Pro';
app.findGlyphPreferences.fontStyle= 'Bold';
app.findGlyphPreferences.glyphID = 102;   //Character:  ¢
app.changeGlyphPreferences.glyphID=8103;  //Desired character, there is no unicode for this, i cant insert it directly, so i have to insert it by glyphs
app.changeGlyphPreferences.appliedFont= 'A-OTF Futo Go B101 Pro';
app.changeGlyphPreferences.fontStyle= 'Bold';
month12day29.characters[0].changeGlyph();
month12day29.characters.everyItem().appliedParagraphStyle ="前ー月大丸";   // same Font A-OTF Futo Go B101 Pro
```

The above part is ok, but when i try to append text to that cell, The inserted character disappeared

```
month12day29.contents +="\r";  /// the Desired chacter above some how got deleted after this line execute
```

I want to ask:

- What is the problem?
- How to work around this?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Seems to work without problems on my side. What type of object is `month12day29`? A character? A word? A paragraph? A table cell?
You can also always go into the story editor and check what exactly are the contents of your text currently.

Comment: Your description says you want to insert text, but the code says you want to change a single glyph into a different glyph. Perhaps the code should attempt to insert text or changeText instead of "changeGlyph"?

Comment: @mdomino its a table cell,  it workfine if the previous character is text type,  i am working in a japanese company and they use alot of weird character (not kanji) and they dont have unicode code for it, they have to insert it rather by open the glyphs panel and pick it by hand, or use js code for it!

Comment: @user1754036  i want to append text to a table cell, be cause they dont have unicode for that character, so i have to insert it by glyph, but when i try to append text to that cell, that character inserted by glyph disapeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with such an exotic glyph that does not even have a unicode, it's probably the JS concatenation that is failing.

In this case you could insert the string you want to append into the table cell's last insertion point. So you can leave your script as is, but as a last step you do this instead:

```js
month12day29.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = "\r";
```

This basically leaves the inserted glyph alone and just places something behind it.